# Will my account be banned if I upvote too much for the same IP address?

Tags: discussion, voting

We have about 200 computers in our office, but the same IP address.

I upvote questions sometimes of my co workers only if they asked good question. A lot of our office mates post too many questions and some of them upvote other co workers' questions.

As I also have their IP address, will it lead to a ban for me also?

But I highly recommend most of them not to upvote simply just because they are co workers.

Comment: You have a problem with UPvoting questions?  That's different!   Why are you upvoting so much?  I get through about 1 upvote a day while running out of downvotes.

Comment: So, you're asking if you can get away with up-voting your coworker's questions?  And they might also up vote yours?  And this doesn't sound like a voting ring to you?  I'd be more concerned about accounts being deleted.

Comment: The number is 584. Any upvotes beyond that, you will be banned. (Seriously though - that number isn't public, for obvious reasons, so the limit can't be gamed.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Wasn't it 127, so the signed byte didn't overflow?

Comment: This has *got to be*  trolling. I can't accept anything else, I really can't.

Comment: Very kind of you to ask for sincere support on how to deal with the situation. Hopefuly, now you'll be able to orient your co-workers that here we don't "follow people", we "follow tags". Regards!

Comment: OK, I have removed it.  Do you know who 'profile 101' is, by any chance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't any limit on how often you vote in an hour.

There is a limit on the number of votes per day - 30, or 40 if you vote on questions.

However, if you vote exclusively (or nearly exclusively) for your coworkers then that **is** a problem. You should be voting on the merits of the post, not who posted it.

Given that you asked here I won't suspend your account (this time), but I have asked for the votes between you and your co-workers to be invalidated.

Comment: ^^ lol, I would never have guessed that you have a history of unacceptable behaviour:)

Comment: @BabyinCoding You are not doing yourself any favours here. Admitting to creating multiple accounts to get round a question ban is going to get those accounts deleted.

Comment: 'so only i upvoted very few of my co workers' - and only a very few of your  co workers upvoted you?

Comment: Put it another way - how many of your co-workers' posts have you downvoted for not being very good?  Would it be a round number?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought:(

Comment: @BabyinCoding It's good that you'll change your voting habits, but, any previous votes that violate voting policies should be invalidated.